# websocket exception : ReceiveAsync and SendAsync can be called simultaneously

Tags: websocket

I have a websocket client in UI side and WebSocket server in C#.
I have a senario where client sending data to server and many data is coming from server to client at same time.After getting some data in UI socket is closing in UI side.
       Getting the exception in server code:

```
The WebSocket is in an invalid state ('Aborted') for this operation. Valid states are: 'Open, CloseSent'.
```

But at the time of sending data from server to client i am checking the below condition :

```
if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
     await socket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, this.cts.Token);
}
```

getting another exception which i think is the main reason:

```
 There is already one outstanding 'SendAsync' call for this WebSocket instance. ReceiveAsync and SendAsync can be called simultaneously, but at most one outstanding operation for each of them is allowed at the same time.
```

so due to the exception, client is disconnecting from server.Is there any solution for this problem?I am not getting any perfect solution.

Comment: How did you solve this problem?